# Show X axis value on mouseover/mousemove

Tags: svg, d3.js, mouseover, axis, mousemove

I'm trying to show the year on the X axis for the current point I am mousing over on my chart.   similar to how it is here: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/11/30/us/tax-burden.html?_r=0

Here is what I'm working on: jsfiddle.net/Rlightner/u3H8h/

I have set the X axis display to none: to hide the whole x axis initially, (**canvasMarket** is the variable for my svg):

```
var xAxisDisplay = canvasMarket.append("g")
      .attr("class", "xaxis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .style("display", "none");
```

Then I've also appended a rectangle  (with "fill": "none" and "pointer-events": "all" as the "overlay" class) to **canvasMarket** with mouseover, mousemove, and mouseout methods, each calling a respective a function:

```
canvasMarket.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("transform", "translate("+-tickPadding+",0)")
      .attr("width", width+(tickPadding*2))
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover).on("mouseout", mouseout).on("mousemove", mousemove);
```

I've also created a mousemove function thate gets the value (d) closest to the mouse, I was trying to use d to reveal the current X value... by using something like xScale(d.date) to select the current X axis date

```
bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,

function mousemove() {
    var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0 > d1 - x0 ? d1 : d0;}
```

thanks in advance for help!

Comment: How is your current `mousemove` function not working?

Comment: Mousemove is working. i'm just trying to figure out how to get only the X axis value (aka date) i'm hovering over to show up

Comment: right now the mousemove function selects the index number in the array that the mouse is closest to.  This variable is "d".  I want to use that d variable to show the ONLY that Xaxis value  (ie only one X axis value will show up at a time and that will be the one wehre the mouse is) I've tried adding this to the mouseover function but it did not work: xAxisDisplay.select(xAxis(d.date)).style("display", null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you can use the [`tickValues()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues) of the axis which allows you to specify tick values explicitly. You would pass in the value you want to show as the only one, although you may want to show the extreme values as well to give some perspective.

The code would look something like this.

```
function mousemove() {
  var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
       i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
      d0 = data[i - 1],
      d1 = data[i],
       d = x0 - d0 > d1 - x0 ? d1 : d0;

  xAxis.tickValues([min,d,max]);
  canvasMarket.select("g.xaxis").call(xAxis);
}
```

Comment: ..do you mind taking a look at what I'm trying to do with your suggestions?  thanks!

Comment: Well, first you would have to set the axis to be visible and then the code I've posted works basically as-is -- http://jsfiddle.net/u3H8h/4/

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment.

Hope this helps - [**HTML Overlay with pageX / pageY**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1087001)